# Time Consumption of Radix Sort

Tags: algorithm

There's a quote in Allen's Book I don't really understand:

> As an example, we could sort all integers that are representable on a computer (`32 bits`) by radix sort, if we did three passes over a bucket size of `2^11`. This algorithm would always be `O(N)` on this computer.

Why `O(N)`?

Comment: Well, what do you think it should be?  It's hard to explain something when we have no idea what your point of misunderstanding might be.

Comment: I'm writing up an explanation, but it'll take me a second

Comment: It's pretty simple. Correctly implemented radix sort spends constant effort per sorted element per pass.  If you have N elements, and you fix the number of passes by saying the inputs are limited in size (here you are saying there will be 3 passes because ceiling(32/11)=3), then total time is O(constant * 3 * N) = O(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My explanation assumes you have an understanding of radix sort.

A computer with a 32 bit word size has `2^32-1` (`4,294,967,295`) possible word-sized integers (from `0x00 00 00 00` to `0xFF FF FF FF`).

A bucket size of `2^11` means that each bucket collects integers by an 11 bit-wide field (0b000 0000 0000 to 0b111 1111 1111)

We can split these integers' bits into 3 sections, like so:

```
0b | 0000 0000 00 | 00 0000 0000 0 | 000 0000 0000
   | ^section 3 ^ | ^  section 2 ^ | ^ section 1 ^
```

1. `Section 1` is the 11 most insignificant bits
2. `Section 2` is the 11 next-most insignificant bits
3. `Section 3` is the 10 remaining bits

### Stage 1

To perform this sort, first integers are bucketed by their `Section 1` bits. The buckets are like so:

```
0bXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXX X000 0000 0000
0bXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXX X000 0000 0001
0bXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXX X000 0000 0011
 ...
0bXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXX X111 1111 1110
0bXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXX X111 1111 1111
```

`X`s represent irrelevant (to this stage) bits. Each integer is put into one of these `2^11` buckets based on its `Section 1` bits. This is an `O(N)` operation. Once complete, the `2^11` buckets are iterated in order from lowest to highest, and the elements are placed into an intermediate list. The elements in this list are now sorted, if you only look at their `Section 1` bits.

### Stage 2

Next, the integers from the `Stage 1` intermediate list are bucketed by their `Section 2` bits. The buckets are like so:

```
0bXXXX XXXX XX00 0000 0000 0XXX XXXX XXXX
0bXXXX XXXX XX00 0000 0000 1XXX XXXX XXXX
0bXXXX XXXX XX00 0000 0001 1XXX XXXX XXXX
 ...
0bXXXX XXXX XX11 1111 1110 1XXX XXXX XXXX
0bXXXX XXXX XX11 1111 1111 1XXX XXXX XXXX
```

Each integer is put into one of these `2^11` buckets based on its `Section 2` bits. This is another `O(N)` operation. Once complete, the `2^11` buckets are iterated in order from lowest to highest, and the elements are placed into a new intermediate list. The elements in this list are now sorted, if you only look at their `Section 1` *and* `Section 2` bits.

### Stage 3

Next, the integers from the `Stage 2` intermediate list are bucketed by their `Section 3` bits. Theoretically, if the computer had a `33 bit` word size, we could use all `2^11` buckets, and sort all possible `33 bit` integers in `O(N)`. But for our purposes only `2^10` buckets are actually required in this stage, like so:

```
0b0000 0000 00XX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
0b0000 0000 01XX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
0b0000 0000 10XX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
 ...
0b1111 1111 10XX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
0b1111 1111 11XX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
```

Each integer is put into one of these `2^11` buckets based on its `Section 3` bits. This is another `O(N)` operation. Once complete, the `2^10` buckets are iterated in order from lowest to highest, and the elements are placed into a new list. Since the `Section 1`, `Section 2`, and `Section 3` bits have all been accounted for, this list is the final, sorted result.

### Summary

This process took 6 `O(N)` processes:

1. Distribute into buckets by `Section 1`
2. Collect from buckets
3. Distribute into buckets by `Section 2`
4. Collect from buckets
5. Distribute into buckets by `Section 3`
6. Collect from buckets

Thus in total, this algorithm is `O(N)`.